# ZeroMQ push/pull pattern

Tags: push, zeromq, pull

I've decided to write a test code to see how pusher - many pullers bundle works and my suspicions came true.

Pullers receive messages in order they were connected, for example 1st message is received by 1st puller connected, 2nd by 2nd, etc. I've simulated a situation when one of the pullers stayed busy after receiving a message, but when it's time came to receive a message, it queued anyway, so I have 'lost' message. That's bad. I want this message to be received by next 'free' puller. Is that real?

My test code. I use zmqpp as bindings

```
void main()
{
    auto _socket = sIpcContext->CreateNewSocket(zmqpp::socket_type::push);
    _socket->bind("tcp://*:4242");


    for (auto i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        new std::thread([&](int _idx)
        {
            auto idx = _idx;
            auto sock = sIpcContext->CreateNewSocket(zmqpp::socket_type::pull);
            sock->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242");

            for (;;)
            {
                std::string msg;
                sock->receive(msg);
                std::cout << idx << " received: " << msg << std::endl;
                if (idx == 1)
                {
                    std::cout << "Puller 1 is now busy" << std::endl;
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10000));
                }
            }
        }, i);
    }

    for (auto i = 0;; ++i)
    {
        _socket->send(std::to_string(i));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

I get this output:

```
0 received: 0
0 received: 1
1 received: 2
Puller 1 is now busy
2 received: 3
0 received: 4
2 received: 6
0 received: 7
2 received: 9
0 received: 10
2 received: 12
0 received: 13
2 received: 15
```

As you can see, 5, 8, and so on are 'missed' but actually queued in puller #1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, push/pull sockets are dumb enough to let that happen. You could use other sockets, such as router/dealer, to send work to a free worker.

Answer (score 2):

The 0MQ Guide explains this case (calls it the Post Office Analogy):

> It's the post office analogy. If you have one queue per counter, and
>   you have some people buying stamps (a fast, simple transaction), and
>   some people opening new accounts (a very slow transaction), then you
>   will find stamp buyers getting unfairly stuck in queues. Just as in a
>   post office, if your messaging architecture is unfair, people will get
>   annoyed.
>
> The solution in the post office is to create a single queue so that
>   even if one or two counters get stuck with slow work, other counters
>   will continue to serve clients on a first-come, first-serve basis.

Long story short, you should be using the ROUTER when dealing with slow running workers.